# How to check if any changes were made in DataGridView

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview

In my Windows application there is a `DataGridView` form that shows data from xml file.

Now I want to check if there any changes in `DataGridView` to ask user does he\she wants to save  current changes that were done in `DataGridView` to the file.

Comment: If you populate the DataGridView with a DataSet table you can use the .GetChanges method to find out which rows, if any, have changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use two events in order to detect any change in the `DataGridView`. These are `CellValueChanged` for detecting changes on fields and `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` for detecting changes in CheckBox type columns.

Set a boolean `flag = true` when either of those events occurs and check the status of this flag when the form is closed or whenever you want to ask the user for saving changes.

**Example code**

```
Dim DGVhasChanged As Boolean

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    DGVhasChanged = False

    //Do stuff to populate the DataGridView

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

    DGVhasChanged = True

End Sub    

Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

    DGVhasChanged = True

End Sub    

//This example check for changes on Form closing but you can check it on any other event (e.g: When a button is clicked)
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

   If DGVhasChanged = True Then           
       Dim response As MsgBoxResult  
       response = MsgBox("Do you want to save the changes?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
       If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
           //Do stuff to save the changes...
           DGVhasChanged= False
       End If
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I see, but can you please give an example code, im new to programming, and dont have enough expirience in this field, thank you beforehand.

Comment: Ive just check it and i noticed that it dont detect deleting/adding new rows in DataGridView, strange...

Comment: Not strange. The above code is not controlling that. Just do the same with `DataGridView.RowsAdded` and `DataGridView.RowsRemoved` events

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using an XML file with 304 timezones.  Button1 loads the DGV and Button2 checks to see if anything changed.

```vb
Dim ds As New DataSet

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pathToXMLFile As String = Environment.GetFolderPath( _
                                                   Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    pathToXMLFile = IO.Path.Combine(pathToXMLFile, "TimeZones.xml")
    dgv1.DataSource = Nothing
    ds.Dispose()
    ds = New DataSet
    ds.ReadXml(pathToXMLFile) 'read the xml
    'after loading all rows are 'changed'
    'set all rows to not changed
    ds.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
    dgv1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0) 'set datagridviews datasource
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim foo As DataTable = ds.Tables(0).GetChanges
    If Not IsNothing(foo) AndAlso foo.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        'there were changes
        Debug.WriteLine(foo.Rows.Count)
        'if you are going to continue to edit
        ds.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.BindingSource1.EndEdit()
    Me.VisitsTableAdapter.Update(Me.Ds11)
    Button1.Enabled = False
    DataGridView1.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(False)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If Button1.Enabled = True Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty = True Then
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation or comments to your code rather than just a block of code with no context.