# Saving Data To DataSet That Has Been Set Up Programmatically

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I am building a form where I need to programmatically set bindings and the dataset (as it is variable and different documents can be loaded in to it). I've managed to get the form to load any information in to a `DataGridView` and also load that information from the `DataGridView` in to some TextBoxes for structured editing:

[image: Example Of Form]

However I am struggling to get the edited information to save back to the database. It won't even update the `DataGridView` with anything. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module DataGridView_Setup

    Public Sub Set_Datasource(mode As Integer)


        Dim connString As String = My.Settings.Database_String
        Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        ' create a data adapter 
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID, [Name Of Person], [SAP Job Number], [Site Name], [Asset Description], [Spares Supplier], [Supplier Contact Name], [Supplier Contact Phone Number], [Supplier Contact Email], [Spares Description], [Part Number], [Quantity To Order], Cost, [Request Date], [Date Ordered], [Ordered By], [Invoice Received], [Invoice Paid], [Method Of Payment], [Date Item Received], [Additional Comments], [Quote Attatchment] FROM Spares", myConnection)

        ' create a new dataset 
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        ' fill dataset 
        da.Fill(ds, "Spares")



        Main.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        Main.DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False


        'Set Site Listbox

        Dim SiteString = My.Settings.SETTINGS_SiteNames
        Dim SiteBox = Main.VIEW_Site.Items

        SiteBox.Clear()

        Do Until SiteString = ""
            Dim ActiveSiteName = Left(SiteString, InStr(SiteString, "¦"))
            ActiveSiteName = ActiveSiteName.Remove(ActiveSiteName.Length - 1)

            With SiteBox
                .Add(ActiveSiteName)
            End With

            SiteString = Replace(SiteString, ActiveSiteName + "¦", "")

        Loop


        'Set DataBindings
        Main.VIEW_Ref.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_Ref.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.ID", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_NameOfPerson.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_NameOfPerson.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Name Of Person", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_SAPJobNo.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_SAPJobNo.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.SAP Job Number", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_Site.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_Site.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Site Name", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_AssetDesc.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_AssetDesc.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Asset Description", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_SparesSupplier.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_SparesSupplier.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Spares Supplier", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactName.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactName.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Supplier Contact Name", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactNumber.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactNumber.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Supplier Contact Phone Number", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactNumber.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactNumber.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Supplier Contact Phone Number", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactEmail.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactEmail.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Supplier Contact Email", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_SparesDesc.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_SparesDesc.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Spares Description", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_PartNumber.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_PartNumber.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Part Number", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_QuantityToOrder.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_QuantityToOrder.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Quantity To Order", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_CostEach.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_CostEach.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Cost", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_DateRequested.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_DateRequested.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Request Date", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_DateOrdered.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_DateOrdered.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Date Ordered", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_OrderedBy.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_OrderedBy.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Ordered By", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_InvoiceReceivedDate.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_InvoiceReceivedDate.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Invoice Received", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Main.VIEW_InvoicePaidDate.DataBindings.Clear()
        Main.VIEW_InvoicePaidDate.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Invoice Paid", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))


        DataGridView_Setup.BindingUpdates()
    End Sub

    Public Sub BindingUpdates()
        Dim curr As DataGridViewRow = Main.DataGridView1.CurrentRow



        Main.VIEW_Ref.Text = curr.Cells("ID").Value
        Main.VIEW_NameOfPerson.Text = curr.Cells("Name Of Person").Value
        Main.VIEW_SAPJobNo.Text = curr.Cells("SAP Job Number").Value
        Main.VIEW_Site.Text = curr.Cells("Site Name").Value
        Main.VIEW_AssetDesc.Text = curr.Cells("Asset Description").Value
        Main.VIEW_SparesSupplier.Text = curr.Cells("Spares Supplier").Value
        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactName.Text = curr.Cells("Supplier Contact Name").Value
        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactNumber.Text = curr.Cells("Supplier Contact Phone Number").Value
        Main.VIEW_SupplierContactEmail.Text = curr.Cells("Supplier Contact Email").Value
        Main.VIEW_SparesDesc.Text = curr.Cells("Spares Description").Value
        Main.VIEW_PartNumber.Text = curr.Cells("Part Number").Value
        Main.VIEW_QuantityToOrder.Text = curr.Cells("Quantity To Order").Value
        Main.VIEW_CostEach.Text = "£" + CStr(curr.Cells("Cost").Value)
        Main.VIEW_DateRequested.Text = curr.Cells("Request Date").Value

        'Handle DBNULL From now on

        If IsDBNull(curr.Cells("Date Ordered").Value) = True Then
            With Main.VIEW_DateOrdered
                .Text = "Not Ordered Yet"
                .BackColor = Color.LightPink
            End With

        Else
            With Main.VIEW_DateOrdered
                .Text = curr.Cells("Date Ordered").Value
                .BackColor = Color.White
            End With

        End If

        If IsDBNull(curr.Cells("Ordered By").Value) = True Then
            With Main.VIEW_OrderedBy
                .Text = "Not Ordered Yet"
                .BackColor = Color.LightPink
            End With
        Else
            With Main.VIEW_OrderedBy
                .Text = curr.Cells("Ordered By").Value
                .BackColor = Color.White
            End With

        End If

        If IsDBNull(curr.Cells("Invoice Received").Value) = True Then
            With Main.VIEW_InvoiceReceivedDate
                .Text = "No Invoice"
                .BackColor = Color.LightPink
            End With
        Else
            With Main.VIEW_InvoiceReceivedDate
                .Text = curr.Cells("Invoice Received").Value
                .BackColor = Color.White
            End With

        End If

        If IsDBNull(curr.Cells("Invoice Paid").Value) = True Then
            With Main.VIEW_InvoicePaidDate
                .Text = "Not Paid"
                .BackColor = Color.LightPink
            End With
        Else
            With Main.VIEW_InvoicePaidDate
                .Text = curr.Cells("Invoice Paid").Value
                .BackColor = Color.White
            End With

        End If





    End Sub

End Module
```

I have set `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` and assumed that this means when the textbox's are changed, it will update the datasource (being the database). I'm guessing this isn't the case as it doesn't work.

What I'd really like is to be able to edit multiple fields on one data row (via the textboxes) and then click the "Save Changes" button to update the Database.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

I've done a bit more research following some comments and answers and have written this code in to my `Save` button:

```
 Public Sub Save()
        Dim myCon = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database_String)


        myCon.Open()

        Dim sqr = "UPDATE [Spares] SET [Name Of Person] = '" & Main.VIEW_NameOfPerson.Text & "', [SAP Job Number] = '" & CInt(Main.VIEW_SAPJobNo.Text) & "', " & _
                "[Site Name] = '" & Main.VIEW_Site.Text & "', [Asset Description] = '" & Main.VIEW_AssetDesc.Text & "', " & _
                "[Spares Supplier] = '" & Main.VIEW_SparesSupplier.Text & "', [Supplier Contact Name] = '" & Main.VIEW_SupplierContactName.Text & "', " & _
                "[Supplier Contact Phone Number] = '" & Main.VIEW_SupplierContactNumber.Text & "', " & _
                "[Supplier Contact Email] = '" & Main.VIEW_SupplierContactEmail.Text & "', [Spares Description] = '" & Main.VIEW_SparesDesc.Text & "', " & _
                "[Part Number] = '" & Main.VIEW_PartNumber.Text & "', [Quantity To Order] = '" & CInt(Main.VIEW_QuantityToOrder.Text) & "', " & _
                "[Cost] = '" & CDbl(Main.VIEW_CostEach.Text) & "', [Request Date] = '" & CDate(Main.VIEW_DateRequested.Text) & "' WHERE [ID] = '" & CInt(Main.VIEW_Ref.Text) & "'"

        Dim Command = New OleDbCommand(sqr, myCon)
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myCon.Close()
    End Sub
```

When the `Command.ExecuteNonQuery` line attempts to execute I get an error that states the following:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Data type mismatch
>   in criteria expression.

**NB:** The string that is produced in `sqr` is:

```
UPDATE [Spares] SET [Name Of Person] = 'Name', [SAP Job Number] = '2', [Site Name] = 'Site', [Asset Description] = 'Asset', [Spares Supplier] = 'Spares Supplier', [Supplier Contact Name] = 'Contact Name', [Supplier Contact Phone Number] = 'Contact Email', [Supplier Contact Email] = 'Contact Number', [Spares Description] = 'Spare Desc', [Part Number] = 'Part Number', [Quantity To Order] = '1', [Cost] = '1', [Request Date] = '12/02/02' WHERE [ID] = '5'"
```

I am obviously using dummy information

I can't be too far away now surely!

Comment: Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436866/how-to-check-if-any-changes-were-made-in-datagridview/22437191#22437191

Comment: Unfortunately, the key part is saving the changes and your answer says `do stuff to save changes`. That's the bit I need

Comment: What exactly is `Main.VIEW_Ref`?  It looks like you may have an extra player involved.

Comment: @Plutonix `Main` is the name of the form, `VIEW_ref` is the name of the textbox (Its on the VIEW tab and is the "reference" field)

Comment: The `Save Changes` button does not have any code assigned to it, this is the bit I am struggling with

Comment: Do you have a TableAdapterManager ? 

If yes, then use `Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ds)` to update the changed the dataset to database.

Comment: @Mahadev, I do not have a `TableAdapterManager`, I have had to programmatically set the `DataGridView` up. If I use a `TableAdapterManager`, wouldn't I be restricting the userform to only work with 1 particular database?

Comment: Where's the login written on Button Click ?

Comment: How do you mean? Where am I attempting to send this information back to the database?

Comment: yes. I don't see any logic written for that.

Comment: @Mahadev - I haven't written any logic for it as I thought `Main.VIEW_InvoiceReceivedDate.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "Spares.Invoice Received", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))` would mean that when a textbox is changed, it will update the database file.

Comment: @SilverShotBee : I don't think that will work. `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` will update the Dataset but that DataSet must be committed to update the Database. Try to figure out that way. Writing a Save logic will be a better option.

Comment: @Mahadev - I have now written some logic for the save button, see updated Question

Comment: Thats not the right way to create SQL.  Use SQL Parameters and your new problem will disappear (you convert the ID textbox to Int, then immediately back to text by putting it in ticks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally resolved the question with the following code, placed inside the Save button:

```
    Public Sub Save()
        Dim myCon = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database_String)


        myCon.Open()

        Dim sqr = "UPDATE [Spares] SET [Name Of Person] = """ & Main.VIEW_NameOfPerson.Text & """, [SAP Job Number] = " & CInt(Main.VIEW_SAPJobNo.Text) & ", " & _
                "[Site Name] = """ & Main.VIEW_Site.Text & """, [Asset Description] = """ & Main.VIEW_AssetDesc.Text & """, " & _
                "[Spares Supplier] = """ & Main.VIEW_SparesSupplier.Text & """, [Supplier Contact Name] = """ & Main.VIEW_SupplierContactName.Text & """, " & _
                "[Supplier Contact Phone Number] = """ & Main.VIEW_SupplierContactNumber.Text & """, " & _
                "[Supplier Contact Email] = """ & Main.VIEW_SupplierContactEmail.Text & """, [Spares Description] = """ & Main.VIEW_SparesDesc.Text & """, " & _
                "[Part Number] = """ & Main.VIEW_PartNumber.Text & """, [Quantity To Order] = " & CInt(Main.VIEW_QuantityToOrder.Text) & ", " & _
                "[Cost] = " & CDbl(Main.VIEW_CostEach.Text) & ", [Request Date] = " & CDate(Main.VIEW_DateRequested.Text) & " WHERE [ID] = " & CInt(Main.VIEW_Ref.Text) & ""


        Dim Command = New OleDbCommand(sqr, myCon)
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myCon.Close()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: That is what i was proposing that you should put a code to Save Button. Anyone it's good that your problem solved.

Comment: As @Plutonix mentioned, we could hack your program so easily! Use Stored Procedures or at the very least parameterised commands in your query. And try saving a `'` in your query, you should be escaping quotes.

Comment: @JeremyThompson its running on a local laptop, in the store room... So no, its not networked to any domain

Answer (score 0):

If the DataTable you use to bind the grid is global, then on button click, you need to remove the record from the DataTable you are wanting to update, then add the edited data back to the DataTable using the same ID then rebind your grid.  This will at least update your visual fields.  To update the database, you need to call an `Update` query sending the new data the records ID.

If your DataTable is not global, setting the visual is different since you have to loop through each record in the grid then remove the correct one then add the edited record again with the same id.  The sending to the database call will still be the same.

Hope this helps get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I believe it has helped me get a bit futher on. I've updated my question to reflect